# Multi Layer Canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm programming a tilebased Game that consists of  multiple Layers.
However, when i draw the map and try to scale the canvas via CSS, i experience the fact, that the tiles of the upper Layer get a border, which is not intended.
the code for drawing the tiles looks like this:

```
for (var key in Nodes) {
        var currentNode = Nodes[key];
        var tileProb = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

        if (tileProb < 2) {
            currentNode.passable = false;
            canvasLayerZero.drawImage(currentNode.img, 0, 0, tileDim, tileDim, currentNode.x * tileDim, currentNode.y * tileDim, tileDim, tileDim);
        }
        else {
            currentNode.passable = true;
            canvasLayerOne.drawImage(currentNode.img, 20, 0, tileDim, tileDim, currentNode.x * tileDim, currentNode.y * tileDim, tileDim, tileDim);
        };
    };
```

what the code does is basicly creating a randomized map, consisting of two kinds of tiles: Rock and Grass. The rock-tiles are drawn on the lower canvas and the grass-tiles on the upper one.
when the tile-to-be-drawn is a rock it gets its passable propperty set to false. 
So my problem, as already mentioned, is that when i scale it via css to zoom in, the upper tiles get a border. It does not happen if i draw everything on the same canvas. But i need multiple canvases to be able do "walk" behind walls etc.

Can someone explain me how to get rid of it ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do not change canvas size using css.

Comment: can you show an example on jsfiddle? It might be a browser related issue because I cannot reproduce it with FF just like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to sub-pixeling.

Default the pixels are drawn at a half pixel offset so when you scale the canvas with CSS (in effect scaling it as an image) this sub-pixeling becomes more visible.

You can try to translate your canvas before drawing the tiles if you need to use CSS:

```
ctx.translate(-0.5, -0.5);
```

Generally it's not a good idea to scale a canvas using CSS. Instead see if the context method `scale()` can help out or resize the tiles before you draw them (cache the new size if speed is essential).